Setting text color with minted inline stopped working
Ever since March, I've been redefining \FancyVerbFormatLine and passing that as formatcom= in order to change the default text color for minted.
Here is a minimal example that does so:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\codefgcolor}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\textcolor{red}{##1}}%
}
\newmintinline[colormono]{text}{formatcom=\codefgcolor}

\begin{document}
With minted env:

\begin{minted}[formatcom=\codefgcolor]{text}
    test1
\end{minted}

With mintinline: \mintinline[formatcom=\codefgcolor]{text}{test2}

With custom inline command: \colormono{test3}
\end{document}

In an old PDF from September 3rd, that works - and using my old laptop I last upgraded in August, I can indeed verify that the MWE works in the same way:

However, some recent upgrade must have broken things. If I build the same example now, I get:

I cannot figure out what changed in my setup that broke this. On both machines, I'm running:

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux)
texlive 2024.2 (and downgrading to 2024.0 didn't change anything as expected)
Pygments 2.18 (downgrading to 2.17 also didn't change anything)

The only difference I can see is Python 3.12.4 vs. .7, but downgrading that did not change anything either. What could be the culprit that broke this?

you haven't shown your log but minted 3 is an almost complete rewrite check your minted versions,

You can use \usepackage{minted2} in your old documents to get the same minted version as in August. However for new documents I'd advise you eventually migrate to the new version.

texlive 2024.2 still ships with minted v2.9, so that wasn't it - however, I found out that on my old laptop, I had the Archlinux minted package installed additionally, which curiously enough, installs minted v2.6 into a different path (which seems to be preferred according to kpsewhich minted.sty) - and sure enough, minted v2.7 had a rewrite of \mintinline which seems like what breaks things... So the big question would be how I could write this so it continues working with more recent minted versions (ideally v3 too).

You don't need to redefine \FancyVerbFormatLine in formatcom. It accepts any styling commands and applies them to the verbatim text. So
\newcommand{\codefgcolor}{\color{red}}

does what you want. It's possible \mintinline used to use \FancyVerbFormatLine but no longer does.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\codefgcolor}{\color{red}}

\newmintinline[colormono]{text}{formatcom=\codefgcolor}

\begin{document}
With minted env:

\begin{minted}[formatcom=\codefgcolor]{text}
    test1
\end{minted}

With mintinline: \mintinline[formatcom=\codefgcolor]{text}{test2}

With custom inline command: \colormono{test3}
\end{document}


This also works with minted2.

Oh, guess I didn't see the forest for all the trees... that indeed seems to work fine. Thanks!
